# making a new variable if each row equal 1

Tags: r, merge

I have a data.frame like this:

```
var1 <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
var2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
var3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
data <- data.frame(id, var1, var2, var3)
```

I want to have a new variable including code 1 if any of the three columns == 1; and equal to zero if all of the three rows ==zero.

New var
1
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
1

Comment: If each of the columns equals 1 or if ANY of the columns equal 1?

Comment: I mean any columns is1

Comment: In your sample data, there are *no rows* where entries from all three columns are equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're only dealing with only 1 and 0.

```
new_var <- as.numeric(rowSums(data[,2:4])>0)
new_var
[1] 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

If you have numbers other than 1 and you want to check for 1 specifically, you can use apply

```
new_var <- as.numeric(apply(data[,2:4]==1,1, any)
new_var
[1] 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

This does not check for the case if there is a number other than 1 and the rest are 0, but you did not specify that as a case.

Comment: For the 2nd case it is better to use `as.numeric(rowSums(data[,2:4] == 1) > 0)`

Comment: I run your code as following. But, the new generated variable is completely missing:     stenosis$n <- as.numeric(rowSums(stenosis[,3:875] == 1) > 0)

Answer (score 0):

In each row, we'll check if any of var1, var2 or var3 is larger than 0 by adding them up.

```
library(dplyr)
new_data <- data %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(new_var = ifelse(sum(var1, var2, var3) > 0, 1, 0))
```